# why am I getting an Theme related error in android studio?

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-theme

I am following a tutorial on how to make a launcher but for some reason when I add this line of code to my main activity with in the manifest the app crashes saying that my app has stopped

```js
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Wallpaper.NoTitleBar"
```

```js
10-18 15:04:25.245  18122-18122/com.example.harrops.h20droidlauncher E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.harrops.h20droidlauncher, PID: 18122
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.harrops.h20droidlauncher/com.example.harrops.h20droidlauncher.HomeLayout}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2400)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2458)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1305)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5598)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:309)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:278)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:252)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
            at com.example.harrops.h20droidlauncher.HomeLayout.onCreate(HomeLayout.java:13)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5459)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2364)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2458)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1305)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5598)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

if I remove the line of code the app runs just fine.

Any help would be great. Thanks as always in advance.

Comment: add logcat to your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If You've begun Your project in Android Studio by default main activity extends 
`ActionBarActivity` which requires the `AppCompat` theme. Change the Java inheritance from `ActionBarActivity` to `Activity` and leave the theme in the manifest as it is. Or use `AppCompat` theme.

Comment: in the mainActivity java file?

Comment: I mean "YourActivity extends ActionBarActivity" -> "YourActivity extends Activity".

Answer (score 1):

To change the Background use:

```
 android:background=" "
```

You selected a wallpaper.

Try this instead

```
android:background="#b6db49">
```

Below you have said that you want to use the theme. So you have to go in the manifest and edit the theme there which is

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Wallpaper.NoTitleBar">
```

Comment: Yes, as you are trying to add a style for a background.  try this instead android:background="#b6db49">

Comment: but i want to be able to use the devices wallpaper

Comment: What you picked inst a wallpaper. It restyles the whole theme on your app. To do this you need to do in the manifest.